# Populating Fragment with data instead of standing blank

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments

I have an activity that fetches a Serializable object from a database in another activity. That object contains a function getName() that returns a string.

I want to set that string as the text of an edit text contained in a fragment. Whatever I do, it's not working. Any help?

Form.java activity - hosts the fragment, this function tries to edit the fragment using the "Patient" object. I am sure the object has been recieved by the activity, since it shows in LogCat.

```
public void Populate(Patient patient) {
        Frag1 fragment = 
                  (Frag1) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(
                               "android:switcher:"+R.id.pager+":0");
              if(fragment != null)
              {
                 if(fragment.getView() != null) 
                 {
                    fragment.setName(patient.getName());
                    fragment.getView().invalidate();
                    Log.d(patient.getName(), "supbrah"); // doesn't return anything :(
                 }
              }
    }
```

Frag1.java - the fragment's code

```
public class Frag1 extends Fragment {

    EditText name;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_form, container, false);

        name = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.name_edit);

        return v;
    }

    public String getName() {
        String patient = name.getText().toString();
        return patient;
    }

    public void setName(String text) {
        name.setText(text);
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what do you mean by "doesn't return anything"? is that output not being logged at all? if so, your fragment is null, findFragmentByTag() isn't working.

Comment: I will investigate if the fragment is null. The output is indeed not logged at all. I will try to change the way I access the fragment perhaps.